# Android - Custom Toast Class

Tags: java, android, toast, android-toast

I am trying to create a class that it´s supossed to show a toast every time that an object of this class is instaciated.
I want to do this so that I don´t have the same toast code repeated in every activity.

```
public class Toast extends android.widget.Toast {
    String toast_text;
    Context toast_context;

    public Toast(String toast_text, Context toast_context) {
        this.toast_text = toast_text;
        this.toast_context = toast_context;

        Toast toast = android.widget.Toast.makeText(this.toast_context.this, this.toast_text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) toast.getView();
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_global);

        TextView messageTextView = (TextView) view.getChildAt(0);
        messageTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        messageTextView.setTextSize(35);

        Typeface face_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "res/font/aldrich.ttf");
        messageTextView.setTypeface(face_font);
        messageTextView.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);

        toast.show();
    }
}
```

These are the following erros:

**On the constructor:** "There is no default constructor available in "android.widget.toast";
**On the first error:** " ')' expected";
**On the second error:** "Cannot resolve method "getAssets" ".

Comment: Can you post the actual error messages, not just the locations where they occur?

Comment: Yes I can. I have edited the question. Thank you for your time 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `toast_context` that you receive through constructor to create `toast` and access `asset`

```
Toast toast = android.widget.Toast.makeText(toast_context, toast_text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

---

```
Typeface face_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(toast_context.getAssets(), "res/font/aldrich.ttf");
```

Beside this, You should use other name than `Toast` to create custom toast

```
class MyToast extends android.widget.Toast {

    public MyToast(String toast_text, Context toast_context) {
        super(toast_context);

        ...

    }
}
```

Comment: While I was trying to solve this I decided to change the name of the class so that no conflicts may occur. After this the only error that I got was the getAssets function in wich your answer solved it! Thank you very muck for you time and help! 